# Ubuntu 19.10: Screen flickering after wake-up from sleep

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, display, flicker, wakeup

### Issue:

Screen starts flickering whenever my laptop wakes up after a sleep or blank screen.

### Steps to reproduce:

1. Let your laptop go to sleep or let its display turn blank.
2. After wake-up, the display starts flickering.

### My machine:

I am using [ASUS FX505DT](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-TUF-Gaming-FX505DD-DT-DU/specifications) which has KDE and i3wm installed.
**PS:** *I also used to face this issue on my previous Ubuntu 19.10 install with Unity.*

**Specifications:**
Processor: AMD® Ryzen™ 5 3550H Processor
Graphics Card: AMD Vega 8 Graphics Card
Graphics Card: NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1650 , with 4GB GDDR5 VRAM

> I know this question might seem like a duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.10 screen flicker after monitor wake up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883067/ubuntu-16-10-screen-flicker-after-monitor-wake-up), but I'm still posting this question because no solution or workaround are fixing this for me.

**Update 1:** I have funneled down the cause for this issue. It seems to happen only after my laptop wakes up from being suspended.
**Update 2:** I can also trigger this bug by switching my display mode from 120Hz to 48Hz. The screen starts flickering as soon as I switch to 48Hz. Reverting back stops the flickering.

Comment: Include system specs into the body of your message: use "edit".

Comment: @vanadium I have added the specs.

Comment: Does it act the same when using the "other" graphics card?

Comment: @heynnema I haven't installed nvidia drivers yet so it only uses the AMD GPU.

Comment: Find version 430.09 at https://www.geforce.com/drivers Try them and report back.

Comment: @heynnema I installed the drivers and had my X server configured by the installer, but after a reboot, Kubuntu got stuck at a black screen before showing the login screen. I uninstalled nvidia using a virtual console which was accessible.

Comment: Please check update 2. I think it might give a clue.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma Yes...why would you try and switch to such a strange frequency?

Comment: @heynnema KDE provides two frequencies for my display in the settings, 48Hz and 120Hz, so I just toggled the frequency.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma well... don't do that. If you leave it set at 120hz, does your original problem go away?

Comment: @heynnema No, the issue of getting flickering screen after wake up is still there.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma I'd reinstall the Nividia drivers and try and troubleshoot why they didn't work for you... then you can try the Nvidia card and eliminate the AMD card/driver as a source of your problem. There's plenty of posts here about Nivdia for you to research.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to get the nvidia drivers working, though I'm pretty sure this is going to be my third attempt to get them working. I'll update back in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I have the identical problem, amd cpu and gpu, but on PC. it only flickers after waking from sleep, and then I can stop it by reducing the refresh rate [to 100hz]. But if I put the refresh rate back to 144, it flickers.

edit:
3900x and 5700xt with a freesync ultrawide monitor at 1080p.

changing kde plasma to 100hz stops flickering, though the monitor can do 144 before suspending. after waking from a suspend, it will flicker at 144hz

Comment: Reducing to what value? [edit[ your answer and update.